# c# xml to csv api results

Tags: c#, xml, csv

I have a script that connects to an api gets orders and writes the xml to a file.

how would i go about writing this to csv instead?

here is the example code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string developerKey = string.Empty;
    string password = string.Empty;
    string accountID = string.Empty;

    developerKey = "xxxxx";
    password= "xxxxx";
    accountID = "xxxxx";

    OrderCriteria criteria = new OrderCriteria();
    criteria.StatusUpdateFilterBeginTimeGMT = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-30);
    criteria.StatusUpdateFilterEndTimeGMT = DateTime.UtcNow;

    // this would be like a Ready-To-Ship Report
    criteria.PaymentStatusFilter = "Cleared";
    criteria.ShippingStatusFilter = "Unshipped";

    criteria.ExportState = "NotExported";
    criteria.DetailLevel = "Complete";
    criteria.PageSize = 20;

    OrderService orderService = new OrderService();
    orderService.APICredentialsValue = new APICredentials();
    orderService.APICredentialsValue.DeveloperKey = developerKey;
    orderService.APICredentialsValue.Password = password;

    try
    {
        criteria.PageNumberFilter = 1;
        while(true)
        {
            APIResultOfArrayOfOrderResponseItem orderResponse = orderService.GetOrderList(accountID, criteria);

            if (orderResponse.Status == ResultStatus.Failure)
            {
                throw new Exception(orderResponse.Message);
            }

            if (orderResponse.ResultData.Length == 0)
                break; // we moved outside the pages that have data on them

            List<string> clientOrderIdentifiers = new List<string>();
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(OrderResponseDetailComplete));
            XmlTextWriter writer = null;
            foreach(OrderResponseItem order in orderResponse.ResultData)
            {
                OrderResponseDetailComplete completeOrder = order as OrderResponseDetailComplete;
                //put the order on the disk as its own file
                using (writer = new XmlTextWriter(string.Format(@"C:\orders\{0}.xml", completeOrder.ClientOrderIdentifier), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, completeOrder);
                }
                //keep the ClientOrderIdentifier so we can send a batch to mark the orders as exported, filtering the orders from future queries
                clientOrderIdentifiers.Add(completeOrder.ClientOrderIdentifier);
            }

            //submit our batch of processed orders
            APIResultOfArrayOfBoolean exportStatusResponse = orderService.SetOrdersExportStatus(accountID, clientOrderIdentifiers.ToArray(), true);

            if (exportStatusResponse.Status == ResultStatus.Failure)
            {
                throw new Exception(exportStatusResponse.Message);
            }

            //make sure each order was succesfully updated
            for (int responseCount = 0; responseCount < exportStatusResponse.ResultData.Length; ++responseCount)
            {
                if (exportStatusResponse.ResultData[responseCount] == false)
                {
                    //order was not successfully marked as exported
                    MessageBox.Show("Order was not successfully marked as exported:" + orderResponse.ResultData[responseCount].ClientOrderIdentifier);
                }
            }
            ++criteria.PageNumberFilter;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { // big catch for the entire function
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

I only need some of the xml as well.

Its currently downloading each order and writing it to a seperate file i just want it all to be in one file ideally.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Service Stack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text), .NET's fastest JSON, JSV and CSV Text Serializers ([more info](http://docs.servicestack.net/text-serializers/json-csv-jsv-serializers)) or other Libaries like [CsvHelper](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/).

For only serialize the orders, you are interested in, first select them with [linq](https://blog.udemy.com/linq-select/):

`var orders =  orderResponse
                  .Select(order => order.SomeProperty && ..)
orders.ToCsv().Print();`